# View Adaper swiping issues in adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

actually i have 4 fragments in my app and i switch the fragments by swiping left or right. I used view pager for swiping the fragments are swiping perfectly but there is a problem if i swipe and fragment B shows but the backend functionality of fragment C runs. If i go to C then backend functionality of D runs. At fragment A first backend functionality of fragment A runs then it automatically shifted to fragment B but front end view is of fragment A

This is adapter

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private int mNumTabs;

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumTabs= numTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                PersonalSettings tab0 = new PersonalSettings();

                return tab0;
            case 1:
                Health tab1 = new Health();
                return tab1;
            case 2:
                Statistics tab2 = new Statistics();
                return tab2;
             case 3:
                Motivation tab3 = new Motivation();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumTabs;
    }

}
```

This is main activity

```
  viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),4);
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }
```

If u want further code i will give u

Answer (score 0):

It because the viewpager will preload the item next to the current item to improve UX (in your case, the item is the fragment)
You can set `offscreenPageLimit` to ViewPager to limit it:

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

But if you do this, you will found the fragment will reload everytime you enter, IMO this is not a good practice.

Comment: My bad, the default&min value of offscreenPageLimit is 1, which means there is 1 offscreen at least. If you really hate the preload, you should try navigation+fragment, it doesn't support swipe basically but it won't preload

Answer (score 0):

Override destroyItem method in FragmentpagerAdapter

```
 @Override
 public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
   // remove your fragment obj from here
 }
```